# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When I am trying to do
"import gin.tf"
I am getting this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin'.
What should I do to resolve this? I updated tensorflow recently so I don't think its a problem with the version.

Comment: Even "from tensorflow import gin" is not working. I am further getting an error ImportError: cannot import name 'gin'

Comment: Did you install `gin` (e.g. `pip install gin-config`)?

Comment: Yeah I just realised I did not have it installed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/google/gin-config/issues/9).

Just use:

```
pip install gin-config==0.1.1
```

Answer (score 9):

Just do the following

```
pip install gin-config
```