# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin.tf',pip install gin-config==0.1.1 not work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I downloaded the T5 model .py file(text-to-text-transfer-transformer) on the official website.

when i run the mtf_model.py,I found the code:

```
import gin.tf
```

introduce the error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin.tf'

but the code:

```
import gin
```

doesn't.

My computer is Macos.When i press command+click,I can enter the gin.tf file,when I click,I enter the tf/**init** file.

I thought it may count to that I have installed the gin,but i can't import gin.tf.
It is so strange,and I tried the "pip install gin-config==0.1.1"([ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298451/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-gin)),it is useless.

Does anyone has solutions?
Thanks in advance.

additional info:
when I run the mtf_model.py(which is inside 'text-to-text/t5/models/mtf_model.py'),the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin.tf'' was introduced. But when I run the main.py(which is inside 'text-to-text/main.py',and it was created by myself),it's not get an error. the two file both have the code:"import gin.tf".

the source file website:
https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/main/t5/models/mtf_model.py

It is part of a package,but have no requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gin-config`](https://pypi.org/project/gin-config/) is now at version 0.5.0. At the command line, enter

```
pip install -U gin-config
```

to update it to the most recent version, and you should be all set.

---

The file you are running, [`mtf_model.py`](https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/main/t5/models/mtf_model.py), is intended to be imported from `t5.models` *after* `t5` has been installed via `pip`. It is not intended to be run directly. The problem is that there is a `gin` directory inside `t5/models` with an `__init__.py` in it, but it does not export a module called `tf`, nor is there a `tf.py` file within that directory. When you try to run `mtf_model.py` directly from that folder, it is trying to import `gin.tf` locally, not from the installed `gin-config` module.

Once you install `t5` properly, you'll be able to write your own program (**not** in the installed `t5` directory) where you can have

```
import gin
import gin.tf

from t5.models.mtf_model import MtfModel
```

and it *should* all work.

Comment: It doesn't work,I run "pip install -U gin-config",it stay the same. I uninstall the gin-config using "pip uninstall gin-config",and run "pip install -U gin-config" again,still not working.

It is so strange,when I run the mtf_model.py(which is inside 'text-to-text/t5/models/mtf_model.py'),the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin.tf'' was introduced.

But when I run the main.py(which is inside 'text-to-text/main.py'),it's not get an error.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the source file you're trying to run? Is it part of a package that has a `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: the orginal file:https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/main/t5/models/mtf_model.py

Comment: these are some other info:

It is so strange,when I run the mtf_model.py(which is inside 'text-to-text/t5/models/mtf_model.py'),the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gin.tf'' was introduced.

But when I run the main.py(which is inside 'text-to-text/main.py',and it was created by myself),it's not get an error.

the two file both have the code:"import gin.tf".

Comment: There seems have no requirements.txt file.

Comment: It is part of a package,but have no requirements.txt file.

Comment: OK, so are you trying to run `mtf_model.py` directly? Did you just `git clone` the repo, then try to run the file? I'm not sure it's intended to be executed directly - it's part of the [`t5`](https://pypi.org/project/t5/) project. Incidentally, if you go to that link, it's recommending using [`t5x`](https://github.com/google-research/t5x), which apparently doesn't have any PyPI (`pip`) releases yet. At any rate, are you following a tutorial or something which is telling you to run `mtf_model.py` directly?

Comment: @learner please see the update to my answer.